# In a jsf web application, a Javascript based session timer works on Chrome but not on IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jsf, richfaces

In a jsf web application based on Seam and Richfaces, I ran into a problem concerning different browsers. The code (and every variation I tried) works flawless in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer (I am testing version 11).

The code is supposed to start and display a session-timeout countdown in the header. In the beginning of the template file, the timeout is retrieved from the application preferences and stored in a hidden field. The countdown timer is reset whenever a new page is loaded, or when an AJAX request is triggered (`resetInactivityTimer()`).

I am having 2 problems in IE:

1. It seems that the `window.onload`function is not triggered on IE. The counter starts working fine when triggered manually in the console.
2. When the counter is started manually, an error occurs when an AJAX request is triggered.

   ```
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
           <title>Title</title>
           <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/img/favicon.ico"  />
           <a:loadStyle src="/stylesheet/theme.css" />
           <ui:insert name="head" />
       </head>

       <body>
           <h:inputHidden id="originalTimeoutId" value="#{preferencesManager.getPreferenceValue(Preference.HTTP_SESSION_TIMEOUT)}"/>
           <a:loadScript src="/scripts/script.js"/>
           <a:region id="status_zone">
               <a:status for="status_zone" forceId="false" id="ajaxStatus" onstart="resetInactivityTimer()">
                        <f:facet name="start">
                           <h:panelGroup>
                               <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; text-align:center; width: 100%; margin-left: -50%;z-index: 10001;" >
                                   <h:graphicImage value="/img/wait.gif"/>
                               </div>
                               <rich:spacer width="95%" height="95%" style="position: absolute; z-index: 10000; cusor: wait;" />
                           </h:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
               </a:status>
               <div class="main">
                   <ui:include src="/layout/header.xhtml" />
                   <ui:include src="/layout/menu.xhtml" />

                   <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                       <ui:insert name="body" />
                   </div>
                   <ui:include src="/layout/footer.xhtml" />
               </div>
           </a:region>

           <script type="text/javascript">
               window.onload = initCountdown();
           </script>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

The countdown timer is displayed in the top right corner in the Header file "header.xhtml", which is loaded in the template, and therefore contained on every page:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<div class="header">
    <s:graphicImage value="#{preferencesManager.getPreferenceByteContent(Preference.LOGO)}" styleClass="logo"/>
    <h:panelGrid width="92%" columns="3" columnClasses="headerCol2,headerCol3,headerCol4">

        <h:outputText styleClass="titel"
                      value="#{cM.getStringProp('de.gai_netconsult.kodaba.text.title')}"/>
        <span class="timer">Automatischer Logout in: </span>
        <h:outputText id="counter" styleClass="timer"></h:outputText>

    </h:panelGrid>
</div>
```

The time is placed at the `id="counter"` position.

This is the Javascript code: "script.js"

```
var hiddenField;
var timeoutInSeconds;
var originalTimeout;
var originalCounter;
var initialized = false;


function initCountdown(){
    // quit if this function has already been called
    if (arguments.callee.done) return;

    // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
    arguments.callee.done = true;

    // do stuff
    startCountdown();
}


function getHiddenField() {
    if (hiddenField != null) {
        timeoutInSeconds = parseInt(hiddenField.value) * 60;
        return timeoutInSeconds;
    }
    try {
        hiddenField = document.getElementById('originalTimeoutId');
    } catch (e) {
        timeoutInSeconds = 0;
    }
    return timeoutInSeconds;
}

function getOriginalCounter(){
    return document.getElementById('counter');
}

function resetInactivityTimer() {
    if (initialized) {
        console.log("resetInactivityTimer - initialized: " + initialized);
        stopCountdown();
        countdown(timeoutInSeconds, 'counter');
    }
}

function startCountdown () {
    timeoutInSeconds = getHiddenField();
    if(timeoutInSeconds == 0) return;
    originalCounter = getOriginalCounter();
    if(timeoutInSeconds == null || originalCounter == null) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            startCountdown()}, 1000);
        }

    if(timeoutInSeconds != null && originalCounter != null){
        initialized = true;
        originalTimeout = timeoutInSeconds;
        countdown(originalTimeout, 'counter');
    }
}

function stopCountdown() {
    var element = document.getElementById('counter');
    clearTimeout(element.timerId);
}

function leadingzero(number) {
    return (number < 10) ? '0' + number : number;
}

function countdown(seconds, target) {
    var element = document.getElementById(target);
    element.seconds = seconds;
    calculateAndShow('counter');
}

function calculateAndShow(target) {
    var element = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (element.seconds >= 0) {
        element.timerId = window.setTimeout(calculateAndShow,1000,target);
        var h = Math.floor(element.seconds / 3600);
        var m = Math.floor((element.seconds % 3600) / 60);
        var s = element.seconds % 60;
        element.innerHTML=
            leadingzero(h) + ':' +
            leadingzero(m) + ':' +
            leadingzero(s);
        element.seconds--;
    } else {
        completed(target);
        return false;
    }
}

function completed(target) {
    var element = document.getElementById(target);
    element.innerHTML = "<strong>Finished!<\/strong>";
}
```

Some things I tried is replacing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = initCountdown();
</script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent('onload', initCountdown());}
    else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('load', initCountdown(), false);}
    else {document.addEventListener('load', initCountdown(), false);}
</script>
```

This leads to a "Typeconflict".

or with:

```
<rich:jQuery name="jcountdown" query="initCountdown()" timing="onload"/>
```

None of this helps.

Comment: It is important to add that I'm using an older version of RichFaces (3.3.4). I found this source here: https://ruleoftech.com/2015/patching-richfaces-3-3-3-ajax-js-for-ie11 , which may solve the 2nd part of the problem described here (related to AJAX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my timer to work in the end and I will post my solution here:

**Problem 1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       startCountdown();
    });
</script>
```

instead of `window.onload = startCountdown();` solves the problem.
**Important:** when using any `console.log()` statements, the function will only be executed when the developer console is opened! (F12).

**Problem 2: (AJAX)**
Richfaces version 3.3 is simply not compatible with any Internet Explorer Version above IE8.
It is important to apply a patch. This [site](https://ruleoftech.com/2013/patching-richfaces-3-3-3-ajax-js-for-ie9) describes the process in detail.

I also had to make many changes to the Javascript code. I am sure this could be much more elegantly written, but I confess I don't really know much Javascript at all... I'm posting my code anyway, in case somebody may find it useful:

```
var hiddenField;
var timeoutInSeconds;
var originalTimeout;
var originalCounter;


function getHiddenField() {
    if (hiddenField != null) {
        timeoutInSeconds = parseInt(hiddenField.value) * 60 -1;
        timeoutInSeconds;
        return timeoutInSeconds;
    }
    try {
        hiddenField = document.getElementById('originalTimeoutId');
    } catch (e) {
        timeoutInSeconds = 0;
    }
    return timeoutInSeconds;
}

function getOriginalCounter(){
    return document.getElementById('counter');
}

function startCountdown () {
    timeoutInSeconds = getHiddenField();
    if(timeoutInSeconds == 0) return;

    originalCounter = getOriginalCounter();

    if(timeoutInSeconds == null || originalCounter == null) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            startCountdown()}, 1000);
        }

    if(timeoutInSeconds != null && originalCounter != null){
        originalTimeout = timeoutInSeconds;
        countdown(originalTimeout, 'counter');
    }
}


function countdown(seconds, target) {
    var element = document.getElementById(target);
    element.seconds = seconds;
    calculateAndShow('counter');
}

function resetCountdown(){
    var element = document.getElementById('counter');
    element.seconds = timeoutInSeconds;
    updateDisplay(element);
}


function calculateAndShow() {
    var element = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (element.seconds > 0) {
        element.timerId = window.setTimeout(calculateAndShow,1000,'counter');
        updateDisplay(element);
        element.seconds--;
    } else {
        completed();
        return false;
    }
}

function updateDisplay(element){
    var h = Math.floor(element.seconds / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor((element.seconds % 3600) / 60);
    var s = element.seconds % 60;
    element.innerHTML =
        leadingzero(h) + ':' +
        leadingzero(m) + ':' +
        leadingzero(s);
}

function leadingzero(number) {
    return (number < 10) ? '0' + number : number;
}

function completed() {
    var element = document.getElementById('counter');
    element.innerHTML = "<strong>Beendet!<\/strong>";
    logoutCallBackToServer();
}
```

Somewhere in one of your xhtml files (template, Header, menu, whatever) you also need to add this line:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="logoutCallBackToServer" immediate="true" action="#{identity.logout}" />
```

This will ensure that the user is actually logged out precisely when the countdown reaches zero, just in case this does not 100% match the actual session time out.